# Append <ul> and <li> in recursive loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, recursion

I have a site collection. I was told I need a recursive loop to do this.

This is what I've tried:

When the site loads, call getSiteTree() which passes the top level website to my getSubSite() function. From there I check if there are any subsites. I have a boolean but I'm not really using it for anything yet, I've just seen it used before for this type of work. Anyways, from there I check if there are any sub sits, if not I log the end of the branch, if there are, I call the function again using the new url and repeat the process. Looking at my console, it seems to work as intended.

```
function getSiteTree(){
  var tree = $('#treeviewList');
  var rootsite = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
  var siteEnd = false;

  getSubSite(rootsite);  
}

function getSubSite(url){
    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetWebCollection",
    webURL: url,
    async: true,
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        var siteUrl; 
        var siteCount = $(xData.responseXML).find("Web").length;

        if(siteCount == 0){
            console.log("end of branch");
            siteEnd = true;
        }else{
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Web").each(function() {
                siteUrl = $(this).attr("Url");
                console.log(siteUrl);
                getSubSite(siteUrl);
            });
      }
    }
    });
}
```

**My questions**: now that I have my sites, I need to take those sites and create something like this but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

```
    <li>Site 1
        <ul>
            <li>sub 1.1</li>
            <li>sub 1.2</li>
            <li>sub 1.3</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>1.3.1</li>
                </ul>
            <li>sub 1.4</li>
            <li>sub 1.5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Site 2
        <ul>
            <li>sub 2.1</li>
            <li>sub 2.2</li>
            <li>sub 2.3</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>2.3.1</li>
                    <li>2.3.2</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have this inital html:

```
      <div id="treeviewDiv" style="width:200px;height:150px;overflow:scroll">
        <ui id="treeviewList"></ui>
      </div>
```

This is the output I can get and what I'm trying to accomplish. Hopefully this clears things up a bit https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsxA4.png:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT?

Comment: There are a lot of undefined terms here (subsites?) I can tell you how to do this if you show us what is coming back that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Is there anyway you could get this back as a json object? FTW, you may want to consider using AngularJS or Knockout, which can bind JSON data to structures like these.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XSLT. I plan on turning the <ul> and <li> tags into an expandable/collapsible navigation of my entire site from one location. Thats why I'm going with HTML and JS

Comment: Without seeing what's returned, it's hard to build the logic needed to do what you're asking. JSON would be best.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz. Subsites are sitse within sites. I can't get the info in json (I don't know how is more accurate). I get the results as an XML response. I'll post a picture of what I get, hopefully that can help.

Comment: Looking at the SPServices documentation, you can retrieve JSON with [$().SPServices.SPXmlToJson](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPXmlToJson)

Comment: is this for sharepoint?

Comment: @Ryan, I don't really know JSON or how it would help/improve what I'm trying to do. But I'll take a look at the documentation and try to figure it out

Comment: @Snowburnt, yea I'm trying to do this for SharePoint. I'm trying to create a sort of a site management tool using SPServices :)

Comment: @Batman If you can get `SPXmlToJson` working, can you post a sample of the JSON returned? We might be able to show you how the JSON can help resolve your issue.

Comment: Yea no problem, just give me some time to figure out what I'm doing :P

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how to change the code above to return JSON. I tried doing it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WLbDD/

Comment: Could you paste the actual XML that gets returned in your fiddle? Probably whatever `xData.responseXML` is.

Comment: @ryan, I used a different Ajax call to get me one XML file which contains all sites and sub sites. Here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZeeHv/

Now I just need to fine a way to parse through the info so I can format the HTML correctly

Comment: My Sharepoint is a little (...ok a lot) rusty. Is a Site a collection of Webs? If so, could you show me the XML for `$().SPServices.GetSite(YourSite)`?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I posted a new question relating to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457437/parsing-date-to-create-a-navigation-paine/19457928?noredirect=1#19457928 Hopefully the XML there contains the info your looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39524/discussion-between-ryan-and-batman)

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do something like this assuming you have a nested object:

```
function buildTree($element, $object) {
    var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
    var $li;
    $object.forEach(function (item) {
        $li = $('<li>' + item.Name + '</li>');
        $ul.append($li);
        if (item.SubCategories.length > 0) {
            buildTree($ul, item.SubCategories);
        }
        $element.append($ul);
    });
}
```

here's a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/snowburnt/uJbE8/1/

For SharePoint, you would send the RootWeb of the site collection and instead of subcategories you'd send the item.webs property.  All of this using a javascript or jquery object, of course.  You could do it some other way, but if you want to recurse it, it helps to have an object that contains other objects of the same "class"

Comment: I'm looking at your example, but I don't have anything like your $input variable.

Comment: With SharePoint you get the Site collection (SPSite class), use the RootWeb property which is a web.  Web has a Webs property, which gets the sub webs.  Send the RootWeb as the initial variable, then send the .Webs property as recursion call.