# Parsing data to create a navigation pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing, loops

I have this XML response: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeeHv/

I'm trying to create something like this using the information from the dump:

```
<UL>
  <li>Academic
    <ul>
      <li>BM</li>
      <li>CMTTE</LI>
      <li>DM</li>
      <li>PM</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>ARCHIVE</li>
</UL>
<ul>
  <LI>ASSOCIATIONS
    <ul>
    <li>BM</li>
    <li>DM</LI>
    <li>PM</li>
    </ul>
  </LI>
</ul>
```

In the end the XML can give me a list of all my sites and subsits:

```
https://hosted.demo.ca 
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/bm 
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/cmtte 
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/dm 
https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/pm 
https://hosted.demo.ca/archive 
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations 
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations/bm 
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations/dm 
https://hosted.demo.ca/associations/pm
```

How  can I go through this information and append ul and li tags to create a site navigation menu?

JS used to get XML:

```
function getAllSites(){
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
    async: true,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status){
      $(xData.responseXML).find("Web").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr("Url"));
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to build a map of indexes based on the depth of the links, the depth is determined by the number of `/` in the `url`.

```
var map = {}; //init the map
for (var i = 0, l = webs.length; i < l; i++) {
  //we create a index for our links based on the depth of them by `/`
  var m = webs[i].attributes['Url'].value.substring(23, webs[i].attributes['Url'].value.length).split('/').length; 

  map[m] = map[m] || []; //make sure we leave alone the old values if there is none init with new array
  map[m].push(webs[i].attributes['Url'].value); //push new value to node
}
console.log(map);
```

`console.log(map);` will output an object similar to this:

```
{
    "1": ["https://hosted.demo.ca", "https://hosted.demo.ca/academic", "https://hosted.demo.ca/archive", ...],
    "2": ["https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/bm", "https://hosted.demo.ca/academic/cmtte", ...],
}
```

From this you can create your list of elements.

Comment: you got me pretty close to what I'm trying to do but it seems like you taught I wanted to group all levels together. (i.e, all level 1 sits go together, all lv2 sites go togeter, etc) That's not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I've updated my OP to show you what I mean